# Details of the new solutions to the three-body problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

> This question is part of [this week's Journal Club session](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5171/8563).

---

These systems look ridiculously fun to construct. Could someone explain the particulars? What are the various types of solutions, and what are their dynamics? How are they different from previously discovered solutions?

[image]

It's been a while since I first saw the article, which is described nicely in

> Physicists Discover a Whopping 13 New Solutions to Three-Body Problem. Jon Cartwright, [Science Now news, 8 March 2013](http://news.sciencemag.org/physics/2013/03/physicists-discover-whopping-13-new-solutions-three-body-problem).

The original paper is at

> Three Classes of Newtonian Three-Body Planar Periodic Orbits. Milovan Šuvakov and V. Dmitrašinović. [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **110** no. 11, 114301 (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.114301). [arXiv:1303.0181](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0181).

Comment: Related: http://motls.blogspot.cz/2013/03/13-new-periodic-solutions-to-3-body.html

Comment: Related: [How trustworthy are numerically-obtained periodic solutions to the three body problem?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83633)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're leaving. Thank you for bringing this fantastic piece of physics to our attention.

Comment: What's so "unclear" about this question? Voting to reopen.

Comment: @DIMension10 I think it's actually pretty clear, but I think it's too broad... so while I disagree with the close reason, I don't think it could be reopened in it's current state (v8). If it were split into a couple of questions it would be great.

Comment: @DIMension10 pay attention to which revision of the question was actually closed before you make comments like that. That being said, I do think this question is pretty broad, and in its current form I'm not in favor of reopening it. Like tpg2114 said, it could perhaps be split into multiple questions and then I'd be okay with it.

Comment: @DavidZ: Uh, my comment was just after the close. But yes, the new form is better. I don't think that it's too broad.

Comment: I don't think this question is trying to solve a specific problem at the moment: it reads like "let's talk about this, it's interesting!". It would be great if the OP could restrict it to a specific question they are interested about instead of a general "getting-to-know-you" question. The latter type is explicitly discouraged here.

Answer (score 3):

The article you posted contains the following reference:

> Milovan Šuvakov and Veljko Dmitrašinović, Phys. Rev. Lett., (2013)

I imagine you will find all the particulars you need in the [arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0181) of that paper.

Comment: If you want a better answer, you will have to be more specific. Did you have difficulty understanding the preprint? Do you feel something is missing from it? If you don't say what it is then it's impossible for anyone to help you.