# A question about the numerical simulation on classical three-body gravitional system

Tags: simulations, three-body-problem

Related to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83633/how-trustworthy-are-numerically-obtained-periodic-solutions-to-the-three-body-pr?rq=1)

Just out of curiosity, I have a question about the current status of classical (Newtonian) three-body gravitional numerical simulation. I found wikipedia is relatively limited on this topic.

Given three stellas, how accurate can we predict their trajectories using numerical methods based on current compuational techniques and computer capacity? Is there any comparison with astrophysics observation? (Presumably we can update our observed initial conditions during calculation)

Comment: have you seen this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83633/how-trustworthy-are-numerically-obtained-periodic-solutions-to-the-three-body-pr?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have and I edited my post. However, seems that post was related to a special class of solutions and the comments do not indicate how accurate the numerical simulations are (maybe I just overlook at the replies)

Comment: I would see a general question out the error analysis of numeric intgrators as a numeric detail and therefore off-topic here. Use [scicomp.se] for questions of this sort. If the question is, instead, about the *achieved* reliability of a particular analysis or group of analyses, that is probably on-topic, but we would need more detail. The short-short version is that classical gravitation simulations have been *extensively* worked on for decades and they are *very* good, indeed.

Comment: The question is about *achieved reliability*. What kind of details do I need to provide? I also expect the result is very good. What I would like to have, is a reference includes a comparison with astrophysics or any other experiment and computed results.

Comment: You understand that much of the work in this field has been to get interplanetary missions where they are going. They can make multiple inner solar system gravity-transfer boosts (Galileo mission), they can thread their way through the Jupiter and Saturn system including a couple of close passes. They can plan a insert on orbit for a cometary rendezvous and shut the space craft down for *year* while it coasts.

Comment: I am wandering (maybe) more chaotic system, like three stellas having similar mass, otherwise sun, moon, and earth are also three body. Anyway, thanks a lot for this example...