# Proof of unsolvability of $n$-body problem for $n\geqslant 3$ in general

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics, many-body, three-body-problem

We know there are general solutions for the 1-body problem and 2-body problem and also we know in some "special cases" there are some possible solutions for [$n$-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) for $n \geqslant 3$. There might not be a general solution to this problem. But I heard it could be possible to [prove there is no general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_impossibility) in terms of elementary functions for $n$-body problem in general.

1. **Now my question is:** What is this proof? Can anybody explain it? Do we have to use the method of "Proof by contradiction"?
2. **And another question:** What approximate methods are used to solve this problem? Numerical analytical methods? Perturbation theory?

Comment: Have you read [the Wikipedia article that describes this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)? If not, this would have made valuable preliminary reading. In particular it mentions [Sundman's theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Sundman.27s_theorem) that tells us there is a general solution for the three body problem, though admittedly one that is not useful in practice.

Comment: Related: [Can we infer the existence of periodic solutions to the three-body problem from numerical evidence?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83633/)

Comment: Please be more precise what you mean by "there is no general solution". No solution *that we can write down in closed form* (also define what a closed form is)? No solution *at all* for some initial conditions?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I meant [proving there is no solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_impossibility) for $n\geqslant 3$ for the equations of motion to be stated in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Related math.SE post (on the topic of proofs of non-existence of elementary solutions): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/439248/143136,

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is there a proof which has been specifically built for $n$-body problem?

Comment: @JohnRennie As far as I can tell solutions from Sundman's theorem aren't closed form, are they (ie they're an infinite series)?